# Кто в Python должен проверять, правильного ли типа аргументы передаются в функцию или метод?

Tags: python

Кто в Python должен проверять, правильного ли типа аргументы передаются в функцию или метод:

1. Программист вызывающий функцию обязан обеспечить правильность типа передаваемого аргумента. Функция не проверяет явно на первых этапах переданный аргумент, а просто использует его как будто он достоверно правильного типа. В процессе работы функции могут самостоятельно сгенерироваться или быть сгенерированы явно различные исключения, которые будут свидетельствовать о неправильном аргументе. Эту исключения будут описаны в docstring
2. Функция явно на первом этапе проверяет тип переданного аргумента и генерирует исключение если что-то нет так, например, TypeError.
3. Что-то иное

?

Например, если в функцию (для примера)  мы передадим не iterable, а целое или вещественное число, то сгенерируется исключение TypeError (т.к. int и float не iterable). Но можно же в самом начале самому явно проверить, например, что переданный аргумент является итерируемым объектом и что-то сгенерировать.

```
def is_positive_or_zero_values(iterable):
    """Проверить все ли элементы в iterable есть числа равные или больше нуля.

    Args:
        iterable: итерируемый объект, содержащий значения на проверку.
    Returns:
        bool: True, если все элементы в iterable есть числа, которые равные или больше нуля..
              False, иначе.
    """
    if iterable:
        if is_numbers(iterable):
            return all(map(lambda x: x >= 0, iterable))
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Эта тема поднималась и в [Python in Nutshell](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596100469.do), и в [Fluent Python](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920032519.do). Pythonic way - вообще не проверять аргументы. Цитата из Glossary:

> Pythonic programming style that determines an object's type by
>   inspection of its method or attribute signature rather than by
>   explicit relationship to some type object ("If it looks like a duck
>   and quacks like a duck, it must be a duck.") By emphasizing interfaces
>   rather than specific types, well-designed code improves its
>   flexibility by allowing polymorphic substitution. Duck-typing avoids
>   tests using type() or isinstance(). **Instead, it typically employs the**
>   **EAFP (Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission) style of programming.**

Answer (score 1):

```
from functools import wraps
import inspect

def checker(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        insp = inspect.getfullargspec(fn)
        for name, _type in insp.annotations.items():
            arg = args[insp.args.index(name)]
            msg = '%s=%s' % (name, arg), '%s - %s' % (_type, _type == type(arg))
            print(msg)
            if not isinstance(arg, _type):
                raise UserWarning(msg)
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


@checker
def testFn(dt: dict, num: int, st: str):
    print('OK\n')


testFn({'key': True}, 1, 'asd')
testFn({'key': None}, 2, 77)
```

out:

```
('num=1', "<class 'int'> - True")
('st=asd', "<class 'str'> - True")
("dt={'key': True}", "<class 'dict'> - True")
OK

('num=2', "<class 'int'> - True")
('st=77', "<class 'str'> - False")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Scripts/python/2016/3/213123.py", line 22, in <module>
    testFn({'key': None}, 2, 77)
  File "C:/Scripts/python/2016/3/213123.py", line 13, in wrapper
    raise UserWarning(msg)
UserWarning: ('st=77', "<class 'str'> - False")
```

Comment: Это не отвечает на вопрос "как правильно".

Comment: а есть правильный способ? все зависит от задачи. Проверка аргументов в декораторе подходит под пункт 3

Comment: Суть вопроса: "когда какой способ выбрать". У вас есть "способ", но нет "когда". Это я к тому, что стоит прокомментировать написанное в ответе, объяснив, когда это уместно.